# Game programming with Java in Linux

Tags: java, linux

Recently I've been craving some game programming. I primarily use Linux, and was wondering if there are any good graphics libraries for Java development on Linux? Google didn't turn up very much useful information on the subject.

Also, would another language be better? I would like to avoid using python -- Ruby and Java are my two favorite languages. There doesn't seem to be much talk about game programming on Linux in general, unfortunately.

Any suggestions/resources? Easy portability or cross-platform functionality would be awesome too.

Oh, and I prefer 2D graphics.

Comment: What kind of game are you making? Just curious.

Comment: Well, I plan to start small, with a remake of Rodent's Revenge. Following that I'm not sure.. hopefully something a bit more active.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about the APIs mentioned in [Pro Java 6 3D Game Development](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781590598177): [Java3D](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/), [JOGL](https://jogl.dev.java.net/), [JInput](https://jinput.dev.java.net/) and [JOAL](https://joal.dev.java.net/) APIs.

> Topics are split into three sections: Java 3D API, non-standard input devices for game playing, and JOGL. Java 3D is a high-level 3D graphics API, and JOGL is a lower-level Java wrapper around the popular OpenGL graphics API.
>
> **You'll look at three non-standard input devices**: the webcam, the game pad, and the P5 data glove.
>
> **Along the way, you'll utilize several other games-related libraries including**: JInput, JOAL, JMF, and Odejava.
>
> **Learn all the latest Java SE 6 features relevant to gaming, including**: splash screens, JavaScript scripting as well as the desktop and system tray interfaces.

Or have a look at [Java 2D Game Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293079/java-2d-game-frameworks) here on SO.

Comment: Looks interesting. I completely forgot to add that I prefer 2D games.. I've never really been into 3D.

I'll take a look though, can't hurt.

Thanks!

Comment: Great 2D games link, Slick2D and Pulpcore look almost perfect for what I need. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

For game programming there's a nice little framework available, [jMonkeyEngine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/index.php), it support both LWJGL and JOGL.

Answer (score 2):

[JOGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL) is supposed to be cross-platform. There's a wrapper which includes additional functionality called [Lightweight Java Game Library](http://www.lwjgl.org/).

Answer (score 1):

How about Flash?  The [PushButton Engine](http://pushbuttonengine.com/) looks fun.

Answer (score 1):

### Golden T Game Engine

I think the [Golden T Game Engine](http://goldenstudios.or.id/products/GTGE/) is the sort of thing that you are looking for. It makes it very easy to get into actually making a game without having to worry about a lot of boilerplate code.

> Golden T Game Engine (GTGE) is an advanced cross-platform game programming library written in Java language.
>   GTGE library provides a complete routines for making 2D game from low level routines such as hardware accelerated 2D graphics, mouse and keyboard input, audio support, game timing, to game specific routines such as sprite, background, collision detection.

...

> GTGE is a high level interface library, it means programmer never has to worry about any low level commands anymore. The only thing left for the programmer is use their imagination and start programming their game.
>   You don't have to know anything about managing graphics, input, and other low level stuff in Java. Instead you can start immediately develop your own game using the latest Java technology, such as bufferstrategy, volatile image, and even OpenGL easily. You can check out GTGE design standard simplicity, generic, and replacable.